# Android spreadsheat-like application scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I have a problem with 2 way scrolling in Android application:
I developped a spreadsheet like application, I hava a lot of EditText and I need both scrolling.

I put a HorizontalScrollView inside a ScrollView but my problem is the following: I can't reach the bottom right part because once I switch horizontal to vertial scrolling, the cursor goes to the top again.

So I am wondering if:

- the problem comes from the scroll, and then what should I do? I searched a good solution for the scrolling but didn't find a working one. Is there a better solution for a spreadshet?
- the problem comes from the EditText, and in that case, I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

try this [2dscrollview](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/) out. haven't tried it myself but you should give it a shot.